# python android module does not work

Tags: android, python, python-2.7

I am making an app with pgs4a but the app crashes just after the loading screen.
I ran adb logcat and it came up with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'map_key'
```

If I remove all the lines that refer to the android module the app works but obviously you cannot do anything like pause the app. Is the android module not included in pgs4a, or is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using RAPT not pgs4a and they use different methods for mapping keys.
See [RAPT documentation](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example/blob/master/main.py).